# Debug Render In Cocos2d Android

Tags: box2d, physics, cocos2d, cocos2d-x, jbox2d

I want to implement debug render for cocos2d android.So I can view how bodies are created.
Right now I use gdx.jar file for box2d and load that jar file following way.

```
static {
      System.loadLibrary("gdx.jar");
}
```

All the desire bodies are created but I need box2d debug renderer. I have search many place for this question but I could not found anything. So please anybody has knowledge regarding this then suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GLES_Render class in TestCpp, which is located in

```
 ./samples/TestCpp/Classes/Box2DTestBed/GLES-Render.cpp
 ./samples/TestCpp/Classes/Box2DTestBed/GLES-Render.h
```

of the download package.

To implement the debug draw, you can draw the debug renderer with your world data after CLayer::draw(); as demonstrated in samples/TestCpp/Classes/Box2DTestBed/Box2dView.cpp ,

```
void Box2DView::draw()
{
    CCLayer::draw();

    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );

    kmGLPushMatrix();

    m_test->m_world->DrawDebugData();

    kmGLPopMatrix();

    CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();
}
```

If you are using old cocos2d-x library you have follow guide [here](http://asmak9.blogspot.hk/2012/08/cocos2d-x-enable-box2d-debugger.html).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the platform. I am working on cocos2d android where I don't found anything you said so please give me other information that I can use. Cocos2d-Android is totally based on Java.

Comment: it is my mistake. you can also remove tag cocos2d-x from the question to reduce confusion.

Comment: So provide me some detail on how to enable debug draw in cocos2d android.